# Remove optional ID routing parameter from URL in Single Page Application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, routes, single-page-application

My orders application is a Single Page Application that uses a custom-directive search dialog and stays on the **/ManageOrders/Index** page URL while processing orders.

However, it is possible for users to get an email notice of an order, with the order link in the mail.  The link includes an ID parameter, which is an optional route parameter of the order ID.  This all works great, except that when the user is working on an email order, the URL will be like **ManageOrders/Index/33**.  Then each subsequent search will find new orders, but still show the **/33** in the URL bar.  This looks bad, and also returns to order 33 on a refresh (without being obvious to the user).

Is this just a downfall of mixing a called page in a SPA, or is there a technique for getting rid of the **/ID** in the URL?

```
[HttpGet]
[Route ("ManageOrders/Index/{id?}")]
public ActionResult Index(int id = 0)
{
  // this Index action is from inside the SPA, as normal
  if (id == 0)
  {
     TempData["StartInTab"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("OrderInfo");

     return View("~/Areas/OM/Views/ManageOrders/ManageOrders.cshtml",
        TempData["Selected_Order_Data"]);
  }
  else  
  // this Index action has an ID being passed in from an external link, 
  //so needs to fetch the data first and start with Follow Ups
  {
     TempData["StartInTab"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("FollowUpTasks")

     var db = new OrdersEntities();
     var selectedOrder = db.ORDERS.Where(x => x.ORDER_ID == id)…
     TempData["Selected_Order_Data"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectedOrder);     

     return View("~/Areas/OM/Views/ManageOrders/ManageOrders.cshtml",
        TempData["Selected_Order_Data"]);

     // RouteData.Values.Remove("id");  // this alternative doesn’t work – it strips the
     // return RedirectToAction("Index");  // action “/Index” in the URL, which is needed
   }
}
```

Also, I tried using the RedirectToAction, but for some reason it strips off the /Index from the URL when the (“id”) is removed, which causes other problems.

Thanks for any better approaches for this.

Comment: There are a few plugins that allow you to change the url without reloading the page.

Comment: Perhaps another alternative to JS libraries to change the URL would be to have a route with a required ID have an action that just puts that ID in tempdata and redirects to the one without an ID?

Comment: Thanks Stephen - thanks to that I searched for Redirect, which I did not know existed (thought it was just RedirectToAction).  So even using the TempData I was able to use `return Redirect("/AM/ManageAppeals/Index");`
which did just as you suggested, redirected back to the Index page with no ID and the TempData values set.  Thanks for the idea!